# Failing to resolve host IP address when taken from user input

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, input

So I am working on a socket listener in python and when I take the host IP as user input, not as a predefined string, it fails to open the connection with the error message included below. When I put the host IP into the code directly as a predefined variable it works fine. I imagine this is happening because of the newline character that gets included at the end of all user input. I wanted to ask if anyone has run into this issue before and if there was any sort of way to filter out the newline character at the end of the user input.

Code:

```
import socket
target_host = raw_input("Please enter a host IP\n")
target_port = *Some Port*
command = "hostname"
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((target_host, target_port))
```

Error:

```
    client.connect((target_host, target_port))
File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Comment: Please `print target_host` and post the output?

Comment: `target_host = target_host.strip()` will remove any newline and spaces on both ends of the string. As a side note: do you have really good reasons to still use Python 2.7 though it will reach its official end of life in January 2020?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try strip. It's not exactly my choice to use 2.7

Comment: Strip fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using .strip() fixed the issue.

Thank you to Thierry Lathuille for the answer in the comments.
https://stackoverflow.com/users/550094/thierry-lathuille